# Incorrect design matrix H while implementing the Kalman Filter

Tags: matlab, gps, kalman-filter

I am trying to implement extended Kalman filter for the estimation of position from GPS pseudoranges. I used the Taylor series to linearize the measurement equation, the code for this is given below.

```
function [H, R, Po] = getHandRMat(currentdata,estimatedRecPos,sigmaNot)

    % Caluclate R and H for calculating Kalman Gain
    R = getErrorCovMatObs(sigmaNot, currentdata);
    
    Po = sqrt((currentdata(:,3)-estimatedRecPos(1)).^2 + ...
            (currentdata(:,4)-estimatedRecPos(2)).^2 +...
            (currentdata(:,5)-estimatedRecPos(3)).^2)+estimatedRecPos(4);
        
    H = [(estimatedRecPos(1) - currentdata(:,3))./Po, ...
            (estimatedRecPos(2) - currentdata(:,4))./Po, ...
            (estimatedRecPos(3) - currentdata(:,5))./Po, ones(size(Po))];
end
```

The state vector consists of [x, y, z, cdt] of the receiver. `currentdata` has the satellite X, Y, Z coordinates and pseudoranges. estimatedRecPos is the state vector.

**Problem**
When I perform the update step `stateVec = stateVec + K*(Z - (H*stateVec));`, the value of `Z - (H*stateVec)` is extremely high, which isn't right. So I'm not sure where I am going wrong. I feel my design matrix H is correct as, I am using the same for Least sq estimation and that seems to work .

** Diff between Actual measurement and predicted measurement**

```
1.0e+07 *

    2.5856
    2.6063
    2.6019
    2.6899
    2.6016
    2.7021
    2.6136
    2.5983
    2.5863
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks

- PS. the algorithm is implemented in Matlab

Update 1: Here is the algorithm presented in probabilistic robotics text book by Sebastian Thrun and Wolfram Brgard.
[image: EKF Filter Algorrithm]

Does this mean that instead of using the design matrix H to convert the state vector to predicted measurement, I directly use the non-linear eq. directly?

Comment: The issue is you are calculating H by dividing the (satellite - user) position  components by Po - but Po includes the clock bias term (estimatedRecPos(4)).  The position terms in the H matrix are from the line-of-sight unit vector, which is (satellite - user) / | (satellite - user) |.